# Visualizing NavisWorks Grids in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a Navisworks model that contais some grids like below: [NavisWorks Grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx2nV.png)

When I visualize this same model in the Forge viewer, I don't see the grids. Is there any way to fix this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6J0y.png)

Comment: f your NWC/NWD files were translated after last April, then you can use this sample to show grids, as starting from then, Model Derivative API generates the AecModelData for NWC/NWD files. You should see grids and levels-related data inside the AecModelData.json.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/tree/dev/public/extensions/AecGridsExtension

Answer (score 0):

If your NWC/NWD files were translated after last April, then you can use this sample to show grids, as starting from then, Model Derivative API generates the AecModelData for NWC/NWD files. You should see grids and levels-related data inside the AecModelData.json.

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/tree/dev/public/extensions/AecGridsExtension

```js
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[0];
let bubble = document.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry() || model.getDocumentNode();

let aecModelData = await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(bubble);
```